# How to store day schedule of a batch in a class and check if it clashes with any other batch already added in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a project for scheduling classes of an institute. One of their requirements was to do a check while scheduling whether the room is already occupied or not at that specific time on that day. I have stored the day schedule as a single column with varchar(7) (for eg: Mon-Fri 0111110, Sunday 1000000, Mon-Wed-Fri 0101010). Now when i insert a new schedule how to check whether it is clashing with any other records already entered

Comment: Well I guess that woulld be a FLOC _Few lines of code_

Comment: This is about the time when you realise that storing information like that looked clever when you thought it up and now realise you have coded yourself into a very dark alley

Comment: @RiggsFolly then can you help me for a way out from the alley :) ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I often chuckle at how succinctly you sum up a problem. I admit that I've done similar things (including this one time where SQL Server wouldn't properly sort a date column under certain conditions which we triggered consistently in testing, but I digress). OP, there are many possible solutions to your problem, one of which is to use the date and time column types provided by MySQL. Without seeing how you're using this data it's tough to design your database for you, though. How are you tracking a particular _time_ when a room is in use, or is a room booked for an entire day?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch _:) I think_  But he is not talking about a date, just a set of flags in a VARCHAR indicating whether a day is taken or free

Comment: exactly @IsaacBennetch

Comment: Okay; "at that specific time on that day" implied differently to me. Personally, then, I'd use a bit field for each day rather than the varchar combination. That would make it pretty easy to run an SQL query against each day.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch Will the usage of 7 bit fields instead for this single varchar field usage make execution slower?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but doing the `SELECT` in SQL based on the bit fields should be faster than reading the varchar field then parsing it.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch Thanks a lot for the information.. I'll look into it